# Squeeze theorem or monotone convergence to solve for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{7^n}}{n!}$$

Squeeze theorem or monotone convergence to solve for convergence, how to use both to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = \frac{\sqrt{7^n}}{n!}$.

Consider the sequence $a_{n+1} / a_n$.

Comment: how do I prove its bound?

Comment: Note that for any $n \geq N$, $a_n = \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}\cdots \frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N}a_N$ and use the behavior of the ratios to determine behavior of $a_n$.

Comment: I got root7/(n+1) how is this non increasing?

Comment: but n is a variable, isn't it suppose to just yield a constant?

Comment: or is it constant/infinity?

Comment: also we cannot use monotone to find limit right? we can only show convergence

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{n+1}$ is decreasing as $n$ increases. However, you do not care about $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{n+1}$ is and of itself. This only tells you how much the sequence changes going from $a_n$ to $a_{n+1}$. What happens when you multiply more and more of the terms in the product of the ratios that equals $a_n$?

Answer (score 0):

**By squeeze theorem**

First, $0\le \sqrt{7^n}\le 7^n=\underbrace{7\cdot 7\cdot 7\cdot{\dots}\cdot 7}_{\text{n times}}$.

Now $$\frac{7^n}{n!}=\frac{7}{1}\cdot{\frac{7}{2}}\cdot{\dots}\cdot{\frac{7}{n}}=\underbrace{\left(\frac{7}{1}\cdot\frac{7}{2}\cdot{\dots}\cdot\frac{7}{7}\right)}_{=C}\cdot\left(\frac{7}{8}\cdot\frac{7}{9}\cdot{\dots}\cdot\frac{7}{n}\right)\le C\cdot\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{n-7}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$

For **monotone convergence** use @user357980 suggestion.

Comment: (7/8 ) ^(n−7)is  (7/8 ⋅7/9 ⋅…⋅7/n )? how so? can I just use <c.(7/n)? Since from 7/8 onwards all less than 1

Comment: Notice the less than sign. It is not equal. Also, you can use 7/n.

Comment: why n-7 is the part that I don't get

Comment: $$\underbrace{\left(\frac{7}{1}\cdot\frac{7}{2}\cdot{\dots}\cdot\frac{7}{7}\right)}_{\text{7 terms}}\cdot\underbrace{\left(\frac{7}{8}\cdot\frac{7}{9}\cdot{\dots}\cdot\frac{7}{n}\right)}_{n-7\text{ terms}}\le C\cdot\underbrace{\left(\frac{7}{8}\cdot\frac{7}{8}\cdot{\dots}\cdot\frac{7}{8}\right)}_{n-7\text{ terms}}=C\cdot\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^{n-7}$$ Understood?

Comment: for the first part, √ 7n ≤ 7 n is it because it is a subsequence of 7n?
.

Comment: @user365103, no, it is because $\forall x\ge 1:\ \sqrt{x}\le x$.

Comment: Thank you for making everything very clear for me